# when asynchronously loaded file is loaded, do some function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am loading in an internal file when some div is clicked, like this:

```
$("div#some").click(function() {
   $("#holder").load(page + ".html");
});
```

The with `.load()` loaded file contains figures and in order to make figure never wider than the containing img, I use this handy code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("img").load(function(){
      $(this).parent().width($(this).width());
   });
});
```

However, this last thing does not seem to apply on asynchronously loaded files with `.load()`. What can I do? I might just add the code:

```
$("div#some").click(function() {
   $("#holder").load(page + ".html");
   $("img").load(function(){
      $(this).parent().width($(this).width());
   });
});
```

But I don't like to insert it since there are possibly more little functions I want to run every time I load something asynchronously from anywhere. Ideally, these lay-out functions are grouped in one nice file `functions.js` so I just include it in the `<head>` of the html-page and never forget one.

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: and someone should edit the question because no language tag is specified

Comment: what is `this` than SLaks?